# Android mediaplayer service best practice

Tags: android, service, media-player

I am currently in the process of writing a music app. Having read around the subject a bit its time to start writing a service and interfacing to it from my main activity.  The Google Dec docs seem to indicate that the main activity should for the heavy lifting and the service should be streamlined as much as possible.  My main activity does quite a lot of work to maintain a play list of songs.  I've been trying (Without success) to pass that play list over to the service when the user clicks play. However, I'm now wondering if I need to do that.

My thinking is that I could let the main activity create the playlist. When user clicks play it sends the first track path, using a string, to the service which handles playing.  The service also has the oncomplete listener. When it triggers it sends a broadcast back to the activity.  When the broadcast is received it would launch the "next" function, which throws the next track to the service.

Would this work in theory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've worked it out for myself.  For those that are interested my theory works perfectly.  The activity handles the play, next, prev etc and playlists.  The service receives instructions from the activity, and requests new instruction via broadcasts.

Comment: how about bound services? i think bound service mechanism is much easier way to interact between activity and service